# Sum all columns, by same ID

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have 12 data.frames with the same variables, but different row numbers. These data.frames have a column ID and 90% of these IDs are the same in all data.frames.

```
ID <- c(1:10)
wage <- c(1500:1509)
bonus <- c(1000:1009)

df1 <- data.frame(ID,wage,bonus)
```

```
ID <- c(1:11)
wage <- c(1800:1810)
bonus <- c(1200:1210)

df2 <- data.frame(ID,wage,bonus)
```

To ease the process, the data.frames are stored in a list, só you can access then like: df[[1]], df[[2]].

I would like to create a new data frame, let's call it new_df, with the same variables but summing all column values by ID (and only the IDs that are present in all data.frames). Since each df have the wages and bonuses for each month, my goal here is to get the annual wage.
I appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To throw out another option, if you have a list with all of your dataframes, you could use `purrr::map_dfr` to bind them all together. In this case the function being mapped is simply to return the dataframe, so it is no different than `bind_rows`. But if you wanted to do something to each dataframe before binding them (e.g. filter), `map_dfr` is a good option.

Also if you want to sum *all* column values by ID  you can use `summarize_all`.

```
library(tidyverse)

list(df1, df2) %>%
  map_dfr(.f = ~.) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize_all(sum)
```

Edit: I missed the filter step that @Karthik S got.  `filter(n() == length(df_lst))` is a nice solution.

```
df_lst <- list(df1, df2) 

df_lst %>%
  map_dfr(.f = ~.) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n() == length(df_lst)) %>%
  summarize_all(sum)
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```
> ID <- c(1:10)
> wage <- c(1500:1509)
> bonus <- c(1000:1009)
> 
> df1 <- data.frame(ID,wage,bonus)
> 
> ID <- c(1:11)
> wage <- c(1800:1810)
> bonus <- c(1200:1210)
> 
> df2 <- data.frame(ID,wage,bonus)
> 
> ID <- c(1:20)
> wage <- c(2001:2020)
> bonus <- c(1301:1320)
> 
> df3 <- data.frame(ID,wage,bonus)
> 
> mylist <- list(df1, df2, df3)
> 
> my_df <- do.call(rbind, mylist)
> 
> my_df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n() == length(mylist)) %>% summarise(tot_wage = sum(wage), tot_bonus = sum(bonus))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
      ID tot_wage tot_bonus
   <int>    <int>     <int>
 1     1     5301      3501
 2     2     5304      3504
 3     3     5307      3507
 4     4     5310      3510
 5     5     5313      3513
 6     6     5316      3516
 7     7     5319      3519
 8     8     5322      3522
 9     9     5325      3525
10    10     5328      3528
>
```

If you want to have option to select any number of columns:

```
> my_func <- function(df, summary_vars){
+   df %>% 
+         summarise(across({{summary_vars}}, sum))
+ }
> my_df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n() == length(mylist)) %>% my_func(wage)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      ID  wage
   <int> <int>
 1     1  5301
 2     2  5304
 3     3  5307
 4     4  5310
 5     5  5313
 6     6  5316
 7     7  5319
 8     8  5322
 9     9  5325
10    10  5328
> my_df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n() == length(mylist)) %>% my_func(bonus)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      ID bonus
   <int> <int>
 1     1  3501
 2     2  3504
 3     3  3507
 4     4  3510
 5     5  3513
 6     6  3516
 7     7  3519
 8     8  3522
 9     9  3525
10    10  3528
> my_df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n() == length(mylist)) %>% my_func(c(wage,bonus))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
      ID  wage bonus
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     1  5301  3501
 2     2  5304  3504
 3     3  5307  3507
 4     4  5310  3510
 5     5  5313  3513
 6     6  5316  3516
 7     7  5319  3519
 8     8  5322  3522
 9     9  5325  3525
10    10  5328  3528
>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked for these variables. But I was thinking in something more generic, since I have 30 variables, although these 2 (wage and bonus) are the most important

Comment: Have edited my answer to add code that will give option of chosing variables. Please check if that works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list `dfs` you can use this `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)

dfs <- list(df1, df2)

bind_rows(dfs) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(wage = sum(wage), bonus = sum(bonus))
```

Comment: How about `bind_rows()` from `dplyr` itself?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to combine `base R` functions to append the two dataframes and then simply aggregate the results.

```
library(dplyr)
do.call('rbind', list(df1, df2)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n() == length(list(df1, df2))) %>%  #as per Karthik S
  summarise_all(., sum)

#       ID  wage bonus
#     <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1  3300  2200
# 2     2  3302  2202
# 3     3  3304  2204
# 4     4  3306  2206
# 5     5  3308  2208
# 6     6  3310  2210
# 7     7  3312  2212
# 8     8  3314  2214
# 9     9  3316  2216
# 10    10  3318  2218
```